# Setup serial port on Virtualbox for working with Pyserial

Tags: serial-port

My host machine's running Ubuntu with Windows XP guest via Virtualbox.

My Ubuntu host have one serial port(/dev/ttyS0), and now I want to use hyperterminal inside XP guest to send & recieve data via serial port(COM0) to my Ubuntu host

On the Ubuntu host I use pyserial to read & write data to XP guest.

How to setup Virtualbox for this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the same serial port on your host and guest OS's.
If yes, you can't.

Or you bind the guest OS serial port to the real serial port and use another serial port on your host (connected by a null modem cable), or you have to use sockets on the host. This socket is created by VirtualBox ( http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#serialports):

> On a Mac, Linux or Solaris host, a local domain socket is used
>   instead. The socket filename must be chosen such that the user running
>   VirtualBox has sufficient privileges to create and write to it. The
>   /tmp directory is often a good candidate.
>
> On Linux there are various tools which can connect to a local domain
>   socket or create one in server mode. The most flexible tool is socat
>   and is available as part of many distributions.

In this case, for on the Linux host, you won't be able to use PySerial.
But on the guest OS, PySerial will work fine, as to the guest OS the virtual serial port will look like a real one.